# How can I pattern match tokens similar to a regular expression?

Tags: regex, algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm looking for a way (algorithm / open source project / ???) to pattern match tokens by constructing a pattern similar to a regular expression or use similar principals.

I'll try to describe my question through examples. Let's say I have the following SQL INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] (Column1) VALUES (@Column1);
```

And let's also say I was able to parse that SQL into tokens (I can), they would look like this:

```
+-------------------+-------+
| INSERT            | token |
| INTO              | token |
| QUOTEDIDENTIFIER  | token |
| DOT               | token |
| QUOTEDIDENTIFIER  | token |
| LEFTPARENTHESIS   | token |
| IDENTIFIER        | token |
| RIGHTPARENTHESIS  | token |
| VALUES            | token |
| LEFTPARENTHESIS   | token |
| VARIABLE          | token |
| RIGHTPARENTHESIS  | token |
| SEMICOLON         | token |
+-------------------+-------+
```

So assuming I have a stream of tokens and I want to match any INSERT statement (and this was the only valid syntax for one) I would write a theoretical regex-esque pattern like this:

```
INSERT\s+INTO\s+
QUOTEDIDENTIFIER\s*DOT\s*QUOTEDIDENTIFIER\s*LEFTPAR\s*IDENTIFIER\s*RIGHTPAR
\s*VALUES\s*LEFTPAR\s*VARIABLE\s*RIGHTPAR\s*;
```

But I know that an INSERT statement can come in various forms like:

```
INSERT INTO Table (  Column1) VALUES (@Column1  )
INSERT INTO Table (Column1, Column2) VALUES (@Column1, @Column2  );
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] (Column1, Column2) VALUES (@Column1, @Column2  );
```

So I could easily make a theoretical regex-esque pattern that would match all token variations of these statements but how can I actually do that?

Why don't I actually use regular expressions? Because I already have the parsed tokens in a stream, seems like there should be a solution to this. I swear I've seen something similar before.

Comment: This seems like an awfully inefficient way to do this.  Why didn't you parse into some sort of P code, or even and AST with genuine objects?

Comment: The name for what you want is a parser.  Tokenization is only the first step of parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Regular Expressions for this.

What you're attempting to do is [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and the tool more appropriate for this job is a **lexical analyzer** or lexer.

If Python is your thing, I've used [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) and had success with it. They're are a [samples scripts](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/example.html) available too that you can reference. If not, most modern languages have libraries or modules available for lexical analysis.